# Modifying default style of TimePicker and DatePicker controls

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I am trying to change the background, pressed state background and color of selected date, time values in ComboBox (that is currently Accent color). The problem is that when I apply the default template available at msdn [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn481539.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn481544.aspx). 
My control changes such that each value in these boxes now have different ComboBox instead of just one. Like in the following image (day, month, year have different ComboBox).

[image] (Image is only for reference)

Also some of the theme resources are missing too like

```
Foreground="{ThemeResource TimePickerHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"

Margin="{ThemeResource TimePickerHeaderThemeMargin}"  

FontWeight="{ThemeResource TimePickerHeaderThemeFontWeight
```

This is how my control look like at the moment without styling applied
[image]

Here is the code I am using

```
            <DatePicker     x:Name="Date_Picker"
                            Header="Date:"
                            Background="{StaticResource HotPink}" 
                            Foreground="{StaticResource Gray05}" />
            <TimePicker     x:Name="Time_Picker"
                            Header="Time:"
                            MinuteIncrement="5"
                            Background="{StaticResource HotPink}"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource Gray05}"/>
```

One more issue is that pink background is only visible on DatePicker and not on TimePicker which is very weird.

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the templates of the controls. Open the project in Blend and find the element in the Document Outline. Right-click and select `Edit Template > Edit a Copy...` (see picture below). This will generate a copy of the default template. From this you can edit the different visual states (which determine how the control will look in different states: active/hover/disabled/etc). When you set the custom values here, they should work as expected.

[image]

**Screenshot from Blend for VS2015**
[image]

Comment: I only have the option of "Create Empty" in all my control's ever since I started with winrt. It was available in silverlight and life was so simple then. Now Blend is of no use.

Comment: Just got home and checked on my regular dev computer. The option is there for my in Blend 2015. It took about 15 seconds from me adding the control to the option to become available, so it looks like it's loading the templates lazily.

Comment: That edit a copy option is still disabled and the default template in vs 2015 is the one on msdn. vs 2013 was using some other template where all fields were in same combobox.

Comment: I just realized that you might be using a shared page (put it in the `Shared` project of your solution). In this case you can't edit the template because it's different on phone and desktop: It's "optimised" for each platform. To be able to style it, you'll have to move at least the xaml file to the platform specific projects. You can still make use of a share code-behind file (.xaml.cs).